# Odd IIS v6 .html file caching behavior: Ideas?

Tags: iis-6

Our loadbalancer looks for "loadbalancer.html"

So today, I deleted the file, but in a browser I could still fetch it.

My eyes crossed, I made sure, 3 ways, that the file was removed from the iis web site home dir. But fetching it gave a nice 200 http response, and the file.

In desperation, I created a new loadbalancer.html, and put some test text in it, and then this new content was retrieved, and then I deleted this file, and THEN it finally gave the 404 as desired.

How can I better understand/control this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS you could set the file to expire immediately. That might help prevent the NLB from caching it.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx

Comment: I don't think the nlb was caching it, since when I changed it it changed immediately. (Unless by changing the file IIS handled it differently)